# Creating a scantron/Bubble form

Tags: forms

I'm trying to create a [custom] bubble/scantron form with LaTeX?

I want to have various fields like *name, last name, date of birth* as well as other fields.

Something like this would be ideal as a start:

[image]

I've been trying to search the net for some packages or functions with no avail.

Can anyone suggest, share or direct me on creating such scantron/bubble forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility with using `tikz`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcounter{cnt}

\newcommand{\alphabet}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]
    \node[draw,circle,minimum size=5mm, inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {};
    \foreach \line in {1,2,...,26} {
        \setcounter{cnt}{\line}
        \node[draw,circle,minimum size=5mm, inner sep=0pt] at (0,-0.6*\line){\Alph{cnt}};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}}

\newcommand{\numbers}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]
    \foreach \line in {0,1,...,9} {
        \node[draw,circle,minimum size=5mm, inner sep=0pt] at (0,-0.6*\line){\line};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}}

\newcommand{\topr}{\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|*{4}{c}|}
\hline
\topr & \topr & \topr & \topr\\[7mm]
\hline
\alphabet & \alphabet & \numbers & \numbers \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### **Edit:**

For alphanumeric column:

```
\newcommand{\alphanum}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]
    \node[draw,circle,minimum size=5mm, inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) {};
    \foreach \line in {1,2,...,26} {
        \setcounter{cnt}{\line}
        \node[draw,circle,minimum size=5mm, inner sep=0pt] at (0,-0.6*\line){\Alph{cnt}};
    }
    \foreach \line [count=\num from 27] in {0,1,...,9} {
        \node[draw,circle,minimum size=5mm, inner sep=0pt] at (0,-0.6*\num){\line};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}}
```

Comment: And what about 2 columns with alpha-numberical "[space]ABCDEF...XYZ012...789"

Comment: @3kstc, see edit of this post.